# Nifi- route the file to two different directories

Tags: apache-nifi

I am having a use case in which I have an input directory which contains around 1000 files. I want to route it to two different destination say directory1 and directory2. I want to route random 500 files to directory1 and remaining 500 files to directory two. My Nifi is set up in cluster mode having one primary and other coordinator node(Only two nodes). I want to balance the load on both the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

For balancing the load in your Nifi cluster you can use site-to-site, remote process group

more info :

https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/load-balancing-across-the-cluster

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/NiFi-Understanding-how-to-use-Process-Groups-and-Remote/ta-p/245486

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-RPG-and-Clustering/td-p/150701

For routing half of the file in a directory, other half in another one you can use counter then route on attribut based of this counter.

some info : https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-count-the-flowfiles-from-incoming-queue-in-nifi/td-p/238951